# Understanding done-fail return with jsonp jquery's Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I don't understand very well jquery's beahavior with jsonp.

This code provides an alert:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://myUrl",
    cache:false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType:'jsonp'
    }).fail(function() {
        alert(getData());
    });
```

This one does not:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://myUrl",
    cache:false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType:'jsonp'
    }).done(function() {
        alert(getData());
    });
```

Notice that *fail* is working whereas *done* is not working...

What did I miss?

Comment: Did you try `then` or `always`? IIRC, `done` means "on success"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code was not properly formed.

Here is a good resource for those who struggle with JSONP ;)

http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/